# PHP/SQL: How to SELECT values from one table that do not exist in a completely different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with a list of projects and who is assigned to each project, and one with names and information about contractors.

```
"Projects_table"
Project_ID    Contractor_assigned    Job_Complete
1             Jim Smith              1
2             John Smith             0
3             Edward Smith           0
4             Smith Smith            1
5             Candle Stick           1
```

and

```
"Contractors_Table"
Contractor_ID    Name              Drywall     Insulation
1                Jim Smith         1           0
2                John Smith        0           1
3                Edward Smith      0           1
4                Smith Smith       0           1
5                Jack BeNimble     0           1
6                Jack BeQuick      1           0
7                Candle Stick      0           1
```

What I need, is to pull an SQL query that gives me a list of the Contractors of a certain type (Drywall or Insulator) who are currently not assigned to any job, so long as that job is also not marked "Complete."

I've tried a few versions of this, but with no success:

```
SELECT
Name FROM Contractors_Table
WHERE Contractors_Table.Insulation=1
AND Name NOT IN
(SELECT Contractor_assigned FROM Projects_table WHERE `Job_Complete` = 0)
```

What I'm hoping for output from my above example is to get back:

```
Jack BeNimble
Candle Stick
```

Those two Insulators are not currently assigned a job, excluding the "complete" job.

Comment: Ummm.  I don't understand this:  "not assigned to any job, so long as that job is also not marked "Complete."  If they are not assigned to any job, how can that (non-existent) job be marked as anything?

Comment: outer join will do it

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess what I meant is that the "Projects_Table" is quite large, and so Jim Smith for example could have been assigned to 50 projects in the past, but they are all now "Complete." I need a list of Contractors who are available for work now, which means I need to know if he's not currently assigned to any other Active job. I know, clear as mud...

Comment: What about JOINS  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join#38578 ? So use `Full outer join` with additional check if `projects_table.field` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT Name
  FROM Contractors_Table c
 WHERE c.Insulation = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 
          FROM Projects_table p
         WHERE p.Job_Complete = 0
           AND p.Contractor_assigned = c.Name)
```

You could refactor the query you are trying to do, but will take much more effort to use `NOT IN`.

You should also use `foreign keys` instead of names to compare data. You are duplicating information in relational database, which doesn't follow [Normalization rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: This query worked! However, I had to change "WHERE Contractors_Table.Insulation = 1" which caused an error to just "WHERE Insulation = 1"

Comment: Updated to make query works. My mistake here, forgot to use table alias.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your table design is wrong: you should store the `Contractor_ID` in the project table, and not their names (what happens with homonyms???)

Secondly I don't understand why your query doesnt return the expected result because it looks correct. Maybe because you have a column named `Name`, and this is a reserved keyword, and you should thus surround it with `

Anyway it's never efficient to do a `NOT IN`

You can rewrite that with an `OUTER JOIN` :

```sql
SELECT C.`Name` 
FROM Contractors_Table C
LEFT JOIN Projects_table P ON C.`Name` = P.`Contractor_assigned` AND P.`Job_Complete` = 0
WHERE C.Insulation=1
  AND P.ID IS NULL --> This will ensure that you only get those who are not in the Project table
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a couple of queries (one for each type). If you use unique ID's in both tables for each of the contractors you can join the tables and select where Contractors_Table.drywall = 0 and Project_Table = 0 (Group by Contractor ID).

I think its just about getting your data sorted in your tables then writing the query.

HTH :-)